# Logical error in a code snippet to arrange an array of numbers

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

This is a code written in java to arrange the array of the numbers in ascending order and then display the maximum and the minimum number. There are no syntax errors, but I think there's a logical error in this as after running the code, the output given is as follows:

```
The numbers are:
3
1
4
5
2
the min number is:3
the max number is:2
15
```

```java
public class Main
{

    public static void main(String args[]) 
    {
        int list[]={2,5,4,1,3};

        int len = list.length;
        int sum=0; 
        int tmp; 
       
       for(int i=0; i<len-1; i++)
       {
           for(int j=0; j<len-i-1; j++)
           {
               if(list[j]>list[j+1]);
               {
                   tmp= list[j];
                   list[j]=list[j+1];
                   list[j+1]=tmp;
               }
           }
       }
       System.out.println("The numbers are:");
       for(int i=0; i<len;i++)
       {
       System.out.println(list[i]);
       }
       System.out.println("the min number is:"+ list[0]);
       System.out.println("the max number is:"+ list[4]);
    
    for (int i=0; i<len; i++)
    sum = sum + list[i];
    System.out.println(sum);
    }
}
```

Comment: I recommend taking a look at [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). This is the sort of skill you'll have to pick up on as a programmer. It's not our job to debug your code.

Comment: Aside from the if semicolon thing, think about the loop invariant for sorting: assuming that `list[0..i-1]` is sorted, update `list` so that `list[0..i]` is sorted. Does the inner loop do that?

Comment: Shouldn't this be closed as a typo?

Answer (score 6):

Remove `;` after statement `if(list[j]>list[j+1]);`
You've terminated the if statement by putting `;`. Remove it to make it work.

This is a valid code, but not correct:

```
if(list[j]>list[j+1]); //<-- if clause with one empty statement.
{                      //<-- here new code block started not related to the if
    tmp= list[j];
    list[j]=list[j+1];
    list[j+1]=tmp;
}
```

Change it to:

```
if(list[j]>list[j+1]) //<-- if clause with 3 statements
{                     
    tmp= list[j];
    list[j]=list[j+1];
    list[j+1]=tmp;
}
```

Tip: you can print arrays using existing API:

```
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(list));
```

Output:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

Answer (score 2):

corrected loop and need to update min and max values while iterating array

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        int arr[]={2,5,4,1,3};

        int len = arr.length;
        int sum=0; 
        int tmp; 
        
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {     
            for (int j = i+1; j < arr.length; j++) {     
               if(arr[i] > arr[j]) {    
                   tmp = arr[i];    
                   arr[i] = arr[j];    
                   arr[j] = tmp;  
                   
               }     
            }           
           
            //System.out.println("The numbers are:");
            System.out.println(arr[i]);
        }    
        
        
        System.out.println("the min number is:"+ arr[0]);
        System.out.println("the max number is:"+ arr[4]);

        for (int i=0; i<len; i++)
            sum = sum + arr[i];
        System.out.println(sum);



    }
```

Comment: I'm not sure why you added extra conditionals to track the current min and max. At the time of printing the min is known to be `arr[0]` and the max is known to be `arr[len-1]`. As far as I can see you are just using additional CPU cycles and memory for no discernible benefit.